# Image changes completely when exported to SVG from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I'm designing stencils for a client in Illustrator. Using only simple path lines with the pen tool, a coupe simple circles and a piece of text -this is the important part- that I converted into outlines so I could erase certain parts (for the breaks of the stencil). Everything looked fine
[image: image just before being exported]
 until I exported it to SVG, I sent it to my client and they got back to me with this picture
[image: It happened to me before and it was just the fault of the eraser, still don't know why but the places where I had erased which were previously invisible exported in grey strokes]
Can anyone tell me what's going on? I've been going crazy for weeks trying to figure it out!!

PS: when I open the sag file in my Illustrator it seems fine, it seems to be just the client that sees it that way.

Thanks for you time!

Comment: I'm beginning to hate SVG because of how varied it is treated between programs. If your client is viewing in inkscape, it might be worth the effort to create the file in inkscape. I often switch between AI and inkscape depending on the design.

Answer (score 1):

You probably left some open paths. Where the errors occur, you should try and connect points so each path is closed. These can be a little tricky to spot if you haven't done it before, basicly you need to find the endpoints where each path is open, then select and join these via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

But why would you need SVG for a stencil? Would PDF not work? Its likely you won't see this 'error' if you save as PDF.

Comment: That makes sense yeah, how would an open path look like, say in this picture for example https://imgur.com/a/97Q6I would it be the darker red points? Also, I did suggest that but my client insists she wants it in svg ._."

Answer (score 0):

> Change the export options.

Sometimes SVG does weirdness in other programs until you mess with the settings. I cannot say for sure what setting will work for you but I had a similar but different problem that was solved by changing the export settings for SVG in illustrator.